# bootstrap selectpicker does not show all data on vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to show an array of data to 'bootstrap selectpicker'.

When I use just plain 'select' element without attaching 'selectpicker'

class, it displays all of data, but when I use 'selectpicker' it won't show

any of data.

I am using vue.js.

Below are the partial code.

#### select picker element

```
<select class="selectpicker">
     <option v-for="dumpdata in dumpdatas">{{ dumpdata }}</option>
</select>
```

#### Getting dumpdatas array

```
axios.get('/api/getDumpDatas')
.then(response => {
    this.dumpdatas = res.data;
});
```

And the above dumpdatas will be saved like a single array. ['A', 'B', 'C'].

dumpdatas variable in vue is defined like

```
data() {
   return {
       dumpdatas: []
   }
}
```

Why selectpicker does not show a single option item, while using just plain select element properly display every item?
[Image of when I use selectpicker, not displaying any data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfS7t.png)

[Image when I use just plain select element with same data pulling method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz5p9.png)

Comment: Would be helpful if you could put together a working demonstration of the problem, a pointer to the component you are trying to use, some code showing how you are using the component, etc.

Comment: If I am understanding your reply correctly. It is a vue.js built in laravel 5.4.  I am just testing using bootstrap selectpicker in vuejs. It is a very simple testing code, and the code I wrote above is pretty much everything. I am getting data from an endpoint 'api/getDumpDatas' when component is mounted. I am wondering why the data does not get displayed in 'selectpicker' while I can clearly see the an array of data in devtool vue panel?

Comment: I'm trying to say, for those of us that don't use laravel, what is a bootstrap selectpicker? A Vue component? A jQuery plugin? How do you instantiate it? Does laravel automatically convert elements with the class `selectpicker` into bootstrap selectpickers? All you've shown is a normal select element, which you also say already works. FWIW, I expect the issue is the picker is somehow initialized, and because you populate the options asychronously, it needs to be *re-initialized* but you don't have any code that does that.

Comment: yeah you were right. It had some data-pulling and populating to the options asynchronously problem. And I was able to manage to fix that. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you fixed it ?